# th:href Thymeleaf redirect url with path variables and object id's with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

So I'm trying to redirect the entire url with a th:href, but it is adding characters that I don't want.

My current url is this

```
http://localhost:8080/viewCourse/post/5
```

And I'm trying to backtrack to the course the post was a part of, which is

```
http://localhost:8080/viewCourse/1
```

So currently this is what my html looks like

```
<a th:href="@{'/viewCourse/'(${post.course.id})}"><span th:text="${post.course.name}"></span></a>
```

And this is the url I get

```
http://localhost:8080/viewCourse/?1
```

And the Id is correct, but I'm not sure why the `?` is there.

I've also tried this

```
<a th:href="@{'/viewCourse/'(id=${post.course.id})}"><span th:text="${post.course.name}"></span></a>
```

Which gives me this

```
http://localhost:8080/viewCourse/?id=1
```

If anybody can see how I can fix this and let me know that would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve adding id without question mark by String concatenation

```
<a th:href="@{/viewCourse/} + ${post.course.id}"><span th:text="${post.course.name}"></span></a>
```

However I would recommend to study this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14938399/5900967

As this can fail in some contexts

Comment: Thanks, it worked, and thanks for the other answer as well, I'll study it.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently your id was added as a parameter.

Your code should be like this:

```
<a th:href="@{/viewCourse/{id}(id=${post.course.id})}"><span th:text="${post.course.name}"></span></a>
```

And the output should be like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/viewCourse/1
```

To learn more about thymeleaf url syntax, see https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html