# Thymeleaf Pagination Url Failed to Convert String to Long

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So I'm trying to paginate results where I have a page with a path variable, and the Thymeleaf th:href keeps telling me `Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'`

So I added an object called "StudySet" to the model in my controller method, like this

```
modelAndView.addObject("studySet", studySetById);
```

And then I try to use it in a th:href in my HTML like this

```
th:href= "@{${studySet.id}/?page=} + ${page}"
```

But my URL just shows up like this

```
http://localhost:8080/studySet/$%7BstudySet.id%7D/?page=2
```

When I want it to look like this

```
http://localhost:8080/studySet/8/?page=2
```

8 is the id of the "studySet" object.

So if anyone has any idea on what I'm doing wrong and could let me know, that would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: is studySetById is an object of StudySet class or a variable ?

Comment: It's a variable, I think, I find the StudySet that I want to pull up using the 'findOne()' method and then I assigned it to 'studySetById'

Comment: try to output `${studySet.id}` somewhere on the page, e.g. `<span th:text="${studySet.id}"></span>` to see if this variable can be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I reproduced your problem and here is a solution:

```
th:href= "@{{studySetid}/?page={page}(studySetid=${studySet.id},page=${page})}"
```

here is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14938344/5151575)  for further reading

Comment: I just noticed that with this solution, when I'm on page 2 and go to page 3, I get this url `http://localhost:8080/studySet/8/8/?page=3`, It duplicates the path variable, do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: never mind, I fixed it with this `"@{/studySet/{studySetid}/?page={page}(studySetid=${studySet.id},page=${page})}"`