# Thymeleaf link with a string value

Tags: thymeleaf

Can i place a string value in thymeleaf link instead of id and without first listing the database table contents. Like this

```
<a th:href="@{particularList/{type}(type=lcd)}">
```

Comment: could you let us know, how the URL has to be genrated for the above template. like a sample url genrated

Comment: I don't have sample. There's a column "type" in my database i want to fetch only those type which will be passed by this url. This Url is the starting point

Comment: Sure you can. I don't understand your question. What exactly did you try so far and what do you want to know? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thymeleaf construct URL with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938344/thymeleaf-construct-url-with-variable)